# VBScript Help clicking facebook menu item

Tags: facebook, button, vbscript, click

Need help clicking a "friends" name in a drop down on Facebook via vbs.  Full code below.  I included pictures and referenced the images in the code to show what each part of the code does and the part I'm having trouble with.  I've spent a full day and deep into the night on this one problem and from what I can tell, it SHOULD be working...but it's not...  I disabled the "submit" feature of the script to prevent accidental submitting of the shared link while testing.  Also, I used a series of wscript.sleep lines as opposed to ie.busy or readystate lines.  I plan to fix this up later...

You'll need to replace "friendsName1" with an actual name from your friend list to test.  You can add multiple separated by commas if you want it to iterate through multiple, but for testing, one is quickest:

```
DistNames = Array("friendsName1")
```

Any help would be awesome.  Very stuck at the moment...

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uleHb.jpg)|[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0yKX.jpg)|[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkyk.jpg)|[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwMiE.jpg)|[Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRt1Y.jpg)

This is how it looks after you've clicked your friends name and it's been successfully added.  I'm trying to achieve this with code...and failing.
    [Image6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nwtq.jpg)

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
 IE.Visible = True

 on error resume next

 '===================================================================
 'Navigates to login page

 ie.navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"
 wscript.sleep 2000

 '===================================================================
 'Logs into FB if you are not already

 if not ie.document.all.item("email") is nothing then

 ie.document.all.item("email").value = "username"
 wscript.sleep 500
 ie.document.all.item("pass").value = "password"
 wscript.sleep 500
 ie.document.all.item("loginbutton").click
 wscript.sleep 2000
 else
 end if

 DistNames = Array("friendsName1")

 For each item in DistNames

 ie.navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"
 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 4000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE1

 'Clicks "share" to open menu 
 for each share in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("a")
 if share.title = "Send this to friends or post it on your timeline." then
 share.click
 exit for
 end if
 next

 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 2000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE2

 'Clicks "Share..."
 for each share1 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("a")
 if instr(share1.getAttribute("ajaxify"),"story_container") > 0 then
 share1.click
 exit for
 end if
 next
 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 5000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE3

 'Opens menu to select who you want it to go to

 for each share2 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("span")
 if share2.innertext = "On your own Timeline" then

 share2.click
 exit for
 end if
 next
 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 1000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE4

 'Selects "On a friend's Timeline"

 for each share3 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("span")
 if share3.innertext = "On a friend's Timeline" then

 share3.click
 exit for
 end if
 next
 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 1000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE5 (Displays friend selection menu - this part works ok)

 'Inserts name from array and opens list to click in the next step

 for each share4 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("input")
 if share4.getAttribute("class") = "inputtext textInput" and  share4.type = "text" then

 share4.value = item
 wscript.sleep 100
 share4.blur
 wscript.sleep 100
 share4.click
 exit for
 end if
 next

 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 2000
 '===================================================================
 'IMAGE5 cont... (Cannot click the name!)

 'Clicks DistList name (not working!!!!)

 for each share5 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("span")
 if share5.getAttribute("class") = "text" and share5.innertext = item  then

 share5.click
 exit for
 end if
 next

 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 2000
 '===================================================================
 'Post body aka "Say something about this..."

 for each share6 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("textarea")
 if share6.name = "message_text"  then

 share6.value = "Check out this post, " & item & "..."
 exit for
 end if
 next

 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 3000
 '===================================================================
 'Clicks "Share Link"

 'for each share6 in ie.document.getElementsbytagname("button")
 'if share6.type = "submit" then

 'share6.click
 'exit for
 'end if
 'next

 next
 '===================================================================
 wscript.sleep 3000
 '===================================================================

 wscript.sleep 500
 wscript.echo "done"
 wscript.quit
```

Comment: Also note that if you want it to log in for you, just add your creds to the top of the script.

Comment: Could you explain what's the purpose of this script? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @JavierdelaCueva My wife is a social media person and she wanted a quick way to post to multiple friends walls - one after the other.  This script would do that if I could get this last piece...